# Filter not working appropriately- when inner joining tables

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, linq, razor

I have a list of students with placement scores that can be sorted or filtered.
I noticed (visually) when filtering the scores do not move with their respective student but instead 
are static.

Example-

Before filter:

```
Student A  |11
Student AA |10
Student B  |09
Student BB |08
```

After filtering by "B" students:

```
Student B  |11
Student BB |10
```

I am assuming it is because their is either incorrect or missing logic happening that tells the code that the student count has been changed. But **I am unsure what I need to be adding to the code to fix this issue and am hoping someone here might be able to point me in the right direction.**

Razor Code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Model.Students[i].LastName</td>
                                <td>@Model.Students[i].FirstName</td>
                                <td>
                                    @* Ept score form group*@
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Students[i].Sid" />
                                        <label asp-for="@Model.Students[i].Score.EptScore">Score</label>
                                        <input type="number" data-internalid="@i" asp-for="@Model.Students[i].Score.EptScore" class="form-control limited-width" aria-describedby="helpBlock1" />
                                        <span id="helpBlock1" asp-validation-for="@Model.Students[i].Score.EptScore" class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
```

Logic Code:

```
IQueryable<Student> StudentsIQ = (from s in _context.Students
                                             where s.StuType == StudentType.New 
                                             && s.YearQuarterEnrolled == quar.Id 
                                             orderby s.LastName, s.FirstName      //default ordering
                                             select s).Include(st => st.Score);

            // Based on input search filters, filter student data
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(LnameSearch))
            {
                StudentsIQ = StudentsIQ.Where(s => s.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(LnameSearch.ToLower()));
                queryParams.Add("LnameSearch", LnameSearch);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SidSearch))
            {
                StudentsIQ = StudentsIQ.Where(s => s.Sid.StartsWith(SidSearch));
                queryParams.Add("SidSearch", SidSearch);
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(FnameSearch))
            {
                StudentsIQ = StudentsIQ.Where(s => s.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(FnameSearch.ToLower()));
                queryParams.Add("FnameSearch", FnameSearch);
            }
    ...
```

Comment: Unrelated tip: You don't need to do `ToLower()` to perform a case-insensitive string comparison. If this is Linq-to-Entities then it's already doing case-insensitive comparisons by default (as per the SQL spec). If this is Linq-to-Objects then use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` or `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. Avoid using `ToLower` to perform comparisons because it causes extra string allocations on the GC heap and because it's vulnerable to the Turkish-I Problem.

Comment: Is `Model.Students` set to an `IQueryable<T>` or did you materialize it (using `.ToList()` or `.ToListAsync()` first? Never expose an `IQueryable<T>` to a View via the ViewModel because the View may be rendered after the parent `IQueryable<T>`'s `DbContext` is disposed - or you may unintentionally serialize your entire database table (very bad).

Comment: @Dai Thank you! This was a super informative tid bit!

Comment: @Dai Model.Students is an IList materalized via ToListAsync before being set as IList Students (Model.Students).

We're not exposing it as an IQueryable<T>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modelstate is stale, so you will want to clear it using `ModelState.Clear()` prior to your async call to the database.

Comment: Eureka! This fixed it!

To elaborate for anyone learning this as well:

The model state was becoming invalid/stale after saving changes to the data; so the application was loading the page/data at the last known point.

Adding: `ModelState.Clear();` right before my iqueryable fixed the issue!